# soql parsing error

Tags: soql

I am getting parsing error  is below query:

```
select 
    id, name, Excercising__c, 
    opportunity__r.id, opportunity__r.Contract.Status 
from option__C 
where 
    opportunity__r.Contract.status__c='current' AND 
    Excercising__c  ='No' AND 
    ( 
        Option_to_Renew_First_Date__c =system.today()+180   OR 
        Market_Review_First_Date_Landlord__c=system.today()+180 OR 
        Excercise_Start_Date__c =system.today()+180 OR 
        Market_Review_First_Date_Tenant__c= system.today()+180
    )
```

can someone please help me out of this?
I am getting parsing error in code between the ()  as I checked after removing them and it is working as expected. Kindly help.

Comment: Isn't it just that you are missing the `:` in front of `System.today()+180` ?

Comment: ye, same and you need to wrap into :(system.today + 180), maybe a good idea to put it into a separate variable before the SOQL

Comment: I tried after putting : , It is still giving parsing error.
I cant add the variable as I am passing this into batch class from schedulable class

Answer (score 3):

Use a colon to specify a bind variable (as also mentioned by others in comment):

```
Option_to_Renew_First_Date__c = :System.today().addDays(180)
```

Another alternative is to use the [SOQL date literals](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm). Example:

```
Option_to_Renew_First_Date__c = NEXT_N_DAYS:180
```

---

Note: `NEXT_N_DAYS` doesn't includes `TODAY`

For adding today in filter, use `Option_to_Renew_First_Date__c IN (NEXT_N_DAYS:180, Today)`

[image]

Comment: @Rahul: Thanks...   I updated my code to Option_to_Renew_First_Date__c = NEXT_N_DAYS:180 and it is working now.  Appriciate you help :)

Comment: Welcome, also the `NEXT_N_DAYS` doesn't include today's date, see my edit if you also want today's record in filter.